# Do i need a separate thread lock for each method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, locking

Here is an example of creating a concurrent hashset object that will be accessed by multiple threads. The 'Add' and 'Remove' methods are both locked via the lock object, _threadLock. Do I need a separate _threadLock for each of the methods or can I share it like it is below?

```
public class ConcurrentHashset<T>
{
    private readonly HashSet<T> _hash = new HashSet<T>();
    private readonly object _threadLock = new object();
    public bool Add(T itemToAdd)
    {
        lock (_threadLock)
        {
            return _hash.Add(itemToAdd);
        }
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        lock (_threadLock)
        {
            return _hash.Remove(item);
        }
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return _hash.Contains(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: You certainly can share it. I would wonder if it is necessary or not to use the same object for both, I would guess yes but am not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two operations *should* share the same lock.

Otherwise, it would be possible to interleave a call to `Add` and another to `Remove`, which could lead to a corrupt hash set.

Furthermore, even though `Contains` only reads the hashset but does not write to it, it also needs to do so inside a lock - otherwise it could risk reading a hash set that is currently being written to by `Add`/`Remove` and be therefore in an inconsistent state.

(Also, a simpler implementation of a concurrent `HashSet<T>` would be to provide a simple wrapper for `ConcurrentDictionary<T, TValue>`, where we simply ignore the values. Note that `ConcurrentDictionary` is lock-free.)

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. Will lock the read methods as well. Is this ConcurrentHashSet class "thread safe" or are there other considerations I should take in to account?

Comment: @geohnH The concurrent dictionary is thread safe, as are all the other collections under the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace. It does all the heavy lifting for you, so you only need a thin wrapper around it, that ignores the values and cares only about the keys.

Comment: Yeh, i compared using the ConcurrentDictionary and using the ConcurrentHashset. Using the ConcurrentHashSet was between 30-50% faster. That's why I was wondering if it would be safe using the ConcurrentHashSet instead of the ConcurentDictionary?

Comment: @geohNH How did you perf test this? Did you warm up the VM? Did you build in Release mode? Was the debugger attached? How big was the sample? How did you time it? What was the degree of parallelism? I can't say whether those numbers are significant :/ If your concurrent hash set is implemented correctly, then yes, I'd say it'd be safe!

Answer (score 0):

Of course the lock must be shared, otherwise there is no point in having a lock in the first place.

If you are accessing an item for read and concurrently accessing it for a removal, things will not work out well.